# Проблема с EditText

Tags: java, android

Добрый день.

Есть `EditText` (поле ввода для срока действия банковской карты формата mm/yy ).

Задача: если ввод начинается с числа(Х) больше 1 его автоматически модифицирует в 0Х ,если первое число 1 второе не должно быть больше 2, после ввода первых двух чисел автоматически ставится символ "/" после него возможен ввод ещё двух чисел. Еще нужно что бы можно было удалять числа в поле ввода. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
editTextValidity.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {//edit text for validity      
   int mCountBefore;
   int mCountAfter;
   int mStartNumber;

   @Override
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
       mCountBefore = count;
   }

   @Override
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
       mCountAfter = count;
       mStartNumber = start;
   }

   @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
       if (mCountAfter > mCountBefore && mStartNumber == 1) {
           s.append("/");
       } else if (mCountAfter < mCountBefore && mStartNumber == 2) {
           s.delete(s.length()-1, s.length());
       }

       if (s.length() == 5) {  
           editTextCardNumber.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.GREEN, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
           editTextCVV.requestFocus();
       }
   }
```

Comment: Все эти манипуляции с полем ввода – излишни. Идеальный вариант: `EditText` с автоматической расстановкой `/` и хинтом, в котором обозначен формат. Второй вариант – спиннеры. А все прочие «удобства » только раздражают. Но если Вы уж очень хотите – лучше использовать уже что-то [готовое](https://github.com/pinball83/Masked-Edittext), чем писать свой велосипед.

Comment: Дорогой  post_zeew не были бы вытак любезны  поделится хмl кодом для данного случая(просто хочется писать ко править что бы те кто будут его дорабатывать или я сам через год не крыли матом меня сегодняшнего)
с нерадивым программистом который только неделю в андроиде

Answer (score 0):

Может есть смысл использовать [DatePickerDialog?](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/datepicker.php) с установкой нужного для Вас формата. Ну или Spiner как тут уже советовали?
Если такие варианты не подходят, надо делать поверку, примерно так:

```
if ( incomDigit < 10){
  myTextViw.setText("0"+incomDigit)
}
```

Comment: Никогда не понимал ответы типа `да нафиг тебе это, вот это бери`

Comment: Что тут не понятного? Довольно часто пытаются придумать велосипед, который уже давно придумали.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте кастомный виджет с форматированным вводом, например [Masked-EditText](https://github.com/pinball83/Masked-Edittext)

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте вывод в поле в `onTextChanged`. при вводе иле изменения `onTextChanged` регирует мнгновено на изменения и сразу вивевит нужный вам результат в поле . поставьте if в `onTextChanged` ... [посмотрите](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q2bjydN_-R4)

Answer (score -1):

В методе `afterTextChanged` напишите:

```
mEditText.removeTextChangedListener(this);

mEditText.setText("0" + s);

mEditText.addTextChangedListener(this);
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы.